# Create server login in SSMS

Tags: sql-server, ssms

I am working with a database and I added a new server login (SQL Server) with the following code:

```sql
if not exists (select * from master.dbo.syslogins 
               where loginname = 'MagaciniArtikliAdmin')
    create login MagaciniArtikliAdmin with password = '123'
```

When I execute:

```sql
select * from dbo.syslogins
```

I get this result:

[image]

instead of this

[image]

Is there anything I am doing wrong?

Comment: Why are you using `dbo.syslogins`? That's for SQL Server 2000 databases. Are you *really* still using SQL Server 2000?

Comment: As for why you see nothing, the `password` field doesn't return anything in the deprecated `dbo.syslogins` view anymore. Not sure *when* this changed exactly though. I suspect the reason is because something changed in the data engine and as the view has been deprecated since 2005, it wasn't updated; as such it returns `NULL`.

Comment: `select * from sys.sql_logins` is what you want

Answer (score 2):

`dbo.syslogins` is deprecated, and does not show the password hash in newer versions of SQL Server.

You want:

```
select * from sys.sql_logins
```